# I'm not able to launch use paramiko or netmiko in my Debian Pi machine

Tags: python

pi@Clone:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Raspbian
Description:    Raspbian GNU/Linux 9.4 (stretch)
Release:        9.4
Codename:       stretch

I had Python 2.7.13 and was trying this bit of code. Then after much searching there were some discussions about this version of Python, and those pre 3.5, did not support f functions so I upgraded and am now using Python3.7. Rather than getting the f something error, now it says 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'netmiko'
I even tried this from the >>> prompt: typing import netmiko, but get the same annoying ModuleNotFound error.
'''
pi@Clone:~$ python3.7
Python 3.7.4 (default, May  2 2020, 09:56:22) 
[GCC 6.3.0 20170516] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

> > > import netmiko
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1, in 
> > >       ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'netmiko'

Tried the below from the cli prompt using python3.7 finename.py

But it never got past the fist command: from netmiko import ConnectHandler. I get the same old error:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'netmiko'

Comment: pi@Clone:~/code$ python3.7
Python 3.7.4 (default, May  2 2020, 09:56:22) 
[GCC 6.3.0 20170516] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import time
>>> import ssl
(time and ssl and I'm sure others import ok, but not netmiko or paramiko)
>>> import netmiko
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'netmiko'

Answer (score 0):

i'm not an expert in python, i've faced the same issue doing my network automation stuff 
and i solved concluding that every instance of python3.x needs its own modules so you need to reinstall netmiko for the new python3.x you got there !!
and you may need to install setuptools and ez_install  for pip and python before installing netmiko.

I hope some expert see this and try to explain in more details for you.